# Android Volley Post Request

Tags: android, android-volley

I have implemented the post request through volley.But it has some strange behaviour. I am getting the response as server not responding but still those post data are inserted database twice.
The parameters are simple string type data that are taken from the edittext fields.Any help on this.

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GlobalConfig.ADD_ACTIVITY_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.e("response", response);                               

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    GlobalCommonMethods.handleErrorResponse(ActivityTeacher.this,error,"Server not responding !!!");
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();
            arguments.put("teacher_id", "ds";

            arguments.put("action", "comment");

            arguments.put("user_type", "teacher");
            return arguments;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: can you post volley error ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the `try {...}` before `catch() {...}`. Below an example of what I mean:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GlobalConfig.ADD_ACTIVITY_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {

                    Something here...

                     } catch (JSONException e) {

                    Something here ...

                     }
                }
            }, ...
```